# SWT Button: delete existing button and add new one

Tags: java, button, swt

I'd like to add buttons dynamically based on what you click in a menu.

[image: first option selected]

The problem I have is that when I select a new option in a menu and deselect the first one, the first one stays on and new one renders under it.

[image: overlaying buttons]

How do I dynamically delete and add new buttons?

My code so far:

```
    table.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            final ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> displaySentences = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
            final ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>> displayDiphones = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < table.getItemCount(); i++) {
                TableItem item = table.getItem(i);
                if (item.getChecked()) {
                    displaySentences.add(new ArrayList<String>());
                    displayDiphones.add(new ArrayList<String[]>());
                    for (int j = 0; j < sentences.get(i).size(); j++) {
                        displaySentences.get(displaySentences.size() - 1).add(sentences.get(i).get(j));
                        displayDiphones.get(displayDiphones.size() - 1).add(diphones.get(i).get(j));
                    }
                }
            }

            int x = 180;
            int y = 10;
            int w = 50;
            for (int i = 0; i < displaySentences.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < displaySentences.get(i).size(); j++) {
                    final Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
                    w = setButtonWidth(displaySentences.get(i).get(j));
                    button.setBounds(x, y, w, 25);
                    button.setText(displaySentences.get(i).get(j));
                    button.setData(displaySentences.get(i).get(j), new int[] { i, j });
                    x += w;
                    if (x > 700) {
                        x = 180;
                        y += 25;
                    }
                    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
                        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                            switch (e.type) {
                            case SWT.Selection:
                                int[] a = (int[]) button.getData(button.getText());

                                for (int k = 0; k < displayDiphones.get(a[0]).get(a[1]).length; k++) {
                                    final Button buttonDiphone = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
                                    buttonDiphone.setBounds(180 + k * 30, 100, 30, 25);
                                    buttonDiphone.setText(displayDiphones.get(a[0]).get(a[1])[k]);
                                    buttonDiphone.setData(displayDiphones.get(a[0]).get(a[1])[k], randomInteger());

                                    buttonDiphone.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
                                                public void handleEvent(
                                                        Event e) {
                                                    switch (e.type) {
                                                    case SWT.Selection:
                                                        txtConsole.setText(buttonDiphone.getText() + ": " + buttonDiphone.getData(buttonDiphone.getText()));
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                }

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you use "final" modifier when declaring your Button? When using "final", the reference to the object Button is a constant, which means that you cannot change its value after affectation. Can you explain your choice? Thanks

Comment: @DanishAshfaq, I used it because Eclipse wouldn't compile if it's not `final`.

Comment: You shouldn't use `setBounds()` but rather use a `Layout`. Then the layout will take care of, well the layout, and you don't have to worry about it. Read [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) to learn about layouts and how to use them.

Comment: @DanishAshfaq OP doesn't change the button, but rather creates a new one each time the `Listener` is fired. `final` or not doesn't make any difference here (except that it won't compile when it's not `final`).

Comment: @Baz, You're right! But maybe a better solution would be to update the text on the buttons that are correctly positioned, and hide/show the others? It's always better not to create too many objects, because the garbage collector works well but is not flawless!

Comment: @Baz thanks for the advice, I'll look it up and let you know if I have any more questions

Comment: @DanishAshfaq I agree in principle, but the OP wants to be able to create one button per item in the list/table. If the list is huge and you create them directly instead of on demand, you might run into other problems.